# What are the knowledge prerequisites for learning Apache Drill?

Tags: apache

I am a n00b to Data Analytics / Big Data Analytics.  I am currently learning statistics and R.  I would like to know the knowledge prerequisites for learning and using Apache Drill, so that I may optimize the learning plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drill is still in alpha and the documentation is very limited. Cloudera Impala may be a better choice short term, if you need stability.

You will need to learn two things - how to get data into a form that Drill can work with, and how to run queries. The latter is simple - learn SQL.

The former is more complicated. The very limited examples use local files in Twitter's Parquet data format, so that would be a good place to start. For more realistic (i.e. distributed) scenarios, learn about HDFS (the Hadoop distributed filesystem) and Zookeeper, HBase, or MongoDB.

Warning - if you are serious about using Drill in a real big data environment (which you shouldn't be, because it is in alpha), you will find this a steep learning curve that takes in a LOT of complex information. A good way to break it down may be:

- SQL - try SQLite
- NoSQL databases - MongoDB
- Distributed filesystems  - HDFS
- Managing distributed environments - Zookeeper
- Distributed key-value stores - HBase
- Real - time distributed queries - Drill or Impala.